# Subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $2 \le n, m \in \mathbb N$, and $SL_n(\mathbb Z; m \mathbb Z)$ be the subset of $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ consisting of matrices of the form $I + X m$, where $X$ is an integer matrix:
$$
SL_n(\mathbb Z; m \mathbb Z) = \{ I + Xm \in SL_n(\mathbb Z) \mid X \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb Z) \}.
$$
Show that

1. $SL_n(\mathbb Z; m \mathbb Z)$ is a normal subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$.
2. If $m = p$ -- prime, then $SL_n(\mathbb Z) / SL_n(\mathbb Z; p \mathbb Z) \cong SL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$.

I think the fact that $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is generated by transvections should be somehow used. Especially for the second question, where it is sufficient to show that there is an equivalence class for any transvection.

Comment: These are called [principal congruence subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#Principal_congruence_subgroups). The only nontrivial thing is that the homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb Z)\rightarrow \operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$ is surjective, which is called weak approximation and is essentially Chinese remainder theorem. All these are detailed in the linked wiki page.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @WhatsUp, could you please be more explicit about surjectivity? I don't see hot the CRT can be useful here. I thought about considering any $\bar A \in SL_n(\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z)$ and $A \in \mathrm(Mat)_n(\mathbb Z)$ s.t. $\bar A = A \mod m$. We need to show that $A$ can be somehow modified to $A' \in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$. Using Smith normal form: $A = B D C$, where $D$ is diagonal and $B, C \in SL_n(\mathbb Z)$, we can reduce the problem to modification a diagonal matrix. But I shill don't see the pattern.

Comment: This I think you have answered yourself: for $k = \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, the group $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ is generated by transvections, thus you only need to show that every transvection in $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ has a preimage in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb Z)$, which is clear (as diagonal elements are all $1$).